# How do I convert a variable (which is a number) to a set string for that variable in Python 3.4?

Tags: python, variables, dictionary

I literally started learning Python yesterday, and I'm kind of stuck. I'm looking at a script someone else made and I'm trying to convert a variable (which will be a number) to a certain string depending on the number. This is what is in the script (the variable being variable1):

```
variable1 = {
    1: 'One'
    2: 'Two'
}
```

etc.

But

```
print variable1
```

returns

```
{1: 'One', 2: 'Two'}
```

I understand why it does that, but how would I make 1 print as One and 2 print as Two and so on? (there's just short of 500 possibilities for the variable)

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Comment: this doesn't seem to be working I still just get {1: 'One', 2: 'Two'} with print

Comment: do you mean you want to `print variable1` and `print variable2`?

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
>>> variable1 = {
        1: 'One',
        2: 'Two'
    }
>>> print variable1[1]
One
>>> print variable1[2]
Two
>>>
```

Comment: I've tried several different 'versions' of this now and the best result so far was 'name 'One' is not defined'

Comment: Are you doing variable1[One] or variable1[1]?